# Windows 10 Unhide folders/files and parent folder disappears

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Having some serious issues with Windows 10. A friend's system crashed, hard, and the SSD was locked out (couldn't unlock it). I put it in a caddy, installed a new HD in the laptop, copied some files over and having a tough time accessing some of them.

The problem basically corrupted her entire profile. She had no backup of her email for the past year! I've grabbed her profile from her old drive, that included the Outlook .pst - her 6gb .pst.

I created a new profile on the new hard drive - still running Windows 10. I copied her old profile into it. When I tried to "unhide" the hidden files/folders from her profile folder "RLG", it went through the motions - the progress bar moving, showing folders/files, it was changing permission on - then, when it was done, the parent folder - RLG - was no longer visible and I can't figure out how to access.

Every profile is an administrator so I'm completely befuddled why logged in as an admin I am denied access to anything. But this disappearing folder - and trying to get it back, is driving me crazy.

Is there something simplistic I am missing? How can an admin, on a Windows 10 system, SEE and ACCESS everything?

Thanks!
Rob

Comment: Your trying to access a Windows file system, on a Windows machine, that has an ACL from the original machine.  You would have to take ownership of every file and folder on the drive to accomplish what you want, which might not be possible, if the drive has seen better days.  This behavior is to be expected since your using a Windows machine to access a NTFS from another Windows machine.

Comment: Hello Ramhound - thanks! But any ideas on the files that I already copied onto the new drive? Why I could see them and then, "unhiding" them made the parent folder disappear? It's still there - it's taking about 36gb of space. When I copied it I was able to see it, data within it. But I wanted to access the "Appdata" folder - so I tried "unhide" - and nothing is visible any longer.

Comment: My guess file system corruption.

Comment: I thought so too but it just seemed odd - the way it happened. But, as the entire profile WAS copied from the damaged drive, anything is possible…But, the really odd thing, I was able to open the .pst file in Windows 7 running Office 2010 on the new drive, using the old profile folders and files. Then, when I upgraded to Windows 10 - Office doesn't even recognize the .pst file as a .pst file. it's a mess…lol…just trying to save the email but it's not looking promising! Thanks again!